# Recursive Number Converter in Java

Tags: java

Attempting to implement the following in java:

- Search online (or make your own) recursive algorithm for converting a Decimal (Base

10. to any Base (2-16).

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Converter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int b, n; 

        System.out.println("Number: ");
        n = sc.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("Base: "); 
        b = sc.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("Result: " + Convert(n, b)); 

    }

    public static int Convert(int n, int b)
    {
        int result;
        if(n < b)
        {
            result = n; 
        }
        else
        {
            result = 10 * Convert(n/b, b) + (n%b); 
        }
        return result; 
    }
}
```

It's working fine, but with something like N = 200 and Base = 15, my program outputs "135", and we're expected to output "D5". I have no idea how to go about this and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry! First time using stackoverflow I'm new to it all, made the changes. 

I assumed so as well, I asked if this output was okay and we were told "it should use appropriate characters for the base" so the output needs to be 6A, not 100.

Comment: Ah sorry, you're right I've confused myself and everyone else by mixing up the numbers. I've tried to make it a little clearer. 

I understand how the conversions work, it's just when there is an output such as 6A, D5, etc, we're expected to output it in that format and I'm not too sure how to implement this.

Comment: I haven't seen the code (I am not a Javascript coder... point 2 of first comment) but `int` as return type will not work for letters - I would recommend a `String` (or a `StringBuilder`) - the `Character` class has methods to convert a number to a single character in a given base (<del>AFAIK</del>, `forDigit()`, if allowed {`Integer` has methods for the whole conversion, as already given in previous comment})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already on the right track.
However, the return type of your function `Convert(int n, int b)`
does not fit yet.
For example: `Convert(200, 15)` needs to return `"D5"`.
Hence the return type should be `String`, but not `int`.

The recursion in your `Convert` is already quite well,
but you need to adapt it to work with strings instead of int.

- Change the return type and also the type of `result` to `String`.
- In your if branch the simple `result = n` will not work anymore.
  Instead, you will need something like `result = convertSingleDigit(n)`
- In your else branch you can keep the logic. But instead of int addition
  you need string concatenation. Something like
  `Convert(n/b, b) + convertSingleDigit(n%b)`
- As seen above you will need a simple helper function
  `String convertSingleDigit(int n)` for converting a single digit
  to a string, for example `1` to `"1"`, or `13` to `"D"`.

Comment: Perfect! This is where I was trying to get to and you've helped connect some of the dots together. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hey, I'm attempting the above and just a little confused with the convertSingleDigit(int n) function. 

I've tried doing different methods of converting my integer into a String, but it always just outputs a blank space.

Comment: @Robin_Hood There are many ways to do it. One way is to use `Character.forDigit(n,16)` and then somehow convert the received `char` to a string. Another way is to write simple but ugly code like `if (n==0) return "0"; if (n==1) return "1"; ...`